# How do I replace a substring of a string before a specific character?

Tags: sql, t-sql, replace, substring

Table `Email`:

Values:

```
josh@yahoo.com
carmine32@hotmail.com
zehmaneh@yahoo.com
```

I want to replace the string before `@` with `test`.

Result:

```
test@yahoo.com
test@hotmail.com
test@yahoo.com
```

How do I use substringing and replace based on a character in the string?

Comment: do you use any server side language?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't even need to use `substring` or `replace`, you can use this:

```
SELECT 'test' + RIGHT(email, charindex('@', REVERSE(email)))
FROM YourTable
```

You can test it out with this:

```
DECLARE @email nvarchar(50)
SET @email = 'carmine32@hotmail.com'
PRINT 'test' + RIGHT(@email, charindex('@', REVERSE(@email)))
```

Comment: @Testifier did you try all the solutions ?

Comment: REVERSE is one of the less performant string functions in TSQL.

Comment: I used this with LEFT to remove any trailing spaces at the end of a string. It worked perfectly. Even strings like "this           " returned "this". Thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 4):

```
declare @t table(email varchar(30))
insert @t values('josh@yahoo.com'),
                ('carmine32@hotmail.com'),
                ('zehmaneh@yahoo.com') 

select stuff(email, 1, charindex('@', email), 'Test@') 
from @t
```

Result:

```
Test@yahoo.com
Test@hotmail.com
Test@yahoo.com
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`SUBSTRING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) and [`CHARINDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx):

```
UPDATE Email set email = 
    'test' + SUBSTRING(email, CHARINDEX('@',email), LEN(email))
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0face/6/0

Answer (score 1):

You could

```
select 'test' + substring(fld, charindex('@', fld), len(fld))
```