# SQL query advice .. writing a query with pattern matching

Tags: sql-server-2008

Folks,

I have a column in MSSQl table as below:

```
| email |
-----------
suzuki@amc.com
yamaha@abc.co
harley@cbc.com
....
```

I want to write a query that will replace everything before the '@' in all the fields with a single work "cars". so the column should look:

```
| email |
-----------
cars@amc.com
cars@abc.co
cars@cbc.com
....
```

Any advice on how I can form this query ?

Answer (score 2):

Many examples of solving this were already discussed here:

[How do I replace a substring of a string before a specific character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371701/how-do-i-replace-a-substring-of-a-string-before-a-specific-character)

For example:

```
UPDATE YourTable set email = 'cars' + SUBSTRING(email, CHARINDEX('@',email), LEN(email))
```

Answer (score 0):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/46ab1/1)**

```
UPDATE Table1 
SET email = 'cars' + 
        SUBSTRING(email, CHARINDEX('@',email), LEN(email)-CHARINDEX('@',email)+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you try this instead ,
first select only the before @ part from mail id 
using this `substring_index(email,'@',1)`

then replace with cars

```
replace(email,substring_index(email,'@',1),'cars')
```

---

```
select replace(email,substring_index(email,'@',1),'cars') from table;
```