# How to replace a substring before and after a specific character in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a SQL variable:

```
SET @TSQL = 'this is test string [this text may vary] other text'
```

Now I want to replace the sub-string "[this text is may vary]" with my own different text.
Can anybody help me? Remember the the sub-string which I want to replace is not static it is dynamic and may vary.

This looks similar to my problem but it is only for before specific character. I need for before and after both characters.

[How do I replace a substring of a string before a specific character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371701/how-do-i-replace-a-substring-of-a-string-before-a-specific-character).

Comment: What is the dependent here? What make that substring distinguishable from the rest of the string. Are the brackets literal? As in will there actually be brackets in your situation?

Comment: Yes, brackets makes sub-string distinguishable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the Substring before '[' add your replacement and the Substring right of ']'

```
declare @TSQL varchar(100)
declare @R varchar(100)
SET @TSQL = 'this is test string [this text may vary] other text'
SET @R = 'MySubstitute'
Select Left(@TSQL,Charindex('[',@TSQL)-1) + @R + RIGHT(@TSQL,Charindex(']',REVERSE(@TSQL))-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it just as simple as this?

```
SET @TSQL = 'this is test string ' + @NewText + ' other text'
```

Or, if the expected-preceding-text is not the only text preceding, maybe:

```
SET @TSQL = 'this is test string [this text may vary] other text'
DECLARE INT @TSQL_PrefixEnding = PATINDEX('%this is test string [[]%[]] other text%', @TSQL) + LEN('this is test string [') - 1
DECLARE INT @TSQL_SuffixStart = CHARINDEX('] other text', @TSQL, @TSQL_PrefixEnding)
SET @TSQL = LEFT(@TSQL, @TSQL_PrefixEnding ) + @NewText + SUBSTRING(@TSQL, @TSQL_SuffixStart, LEN(@TSQL) - @TSQL_SuffixStart + 1)
```

(Note:  I'd have to test it, to see if the "+1" is necessary or not... but it's just a common kind of adjustment I've seen, in string-length calculation.)

---

Notes re' answer & edits: 
 
-- My answer was written as if `'this is test string '`, etc. were strings to *recognize*. 
 
-- Patindex (replacing Charindex) means you ONLY recognize the prefix-string, when the suffix-string is also present. 
 
-- I added `[` to the string before, and `]` to the string after, (wherever they occur) based on your later comment, that had it sound like the brackets are actually part of the string to recognize. 
 
-- The `[` is itself enclosed, in `[` and `]`, to "escape" it -- so it will be interpreted literally.

Answer (score 1):

STUFF does this nicely.

```
declare @string         [nvarchar](max) = N'This is a boilerplate string where [this text may vary] but this text should stay'
    , @replace_me   [nvarchar](max) = N'[this text may vary]'
    , @replace_with [nvarchar](max) = N'cool new stuff!';
select stuff (@string
          , charindex(@replace_me
                     , @string)
          , len(@replace_me)
          , @replace_with);
```